# How to handle $broadcast for loading spinner with ajax and file uploads

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using some code I found in [this GIST](https://gist.github.com/michaelhunziker/407696d85230cb4e5868):

```
.factory('httpInterceptor', function ($q, $rootScope, $log) {
    var numLoadings = 0;
    return {
        request: function (config) {
            numLoadings++;

            // Show loader
            $rootScope.$broadcast("loader_show");
            return config || $q.when(config)
        },
        response: function (response) {

            if ((--numLoadings) === 0) {
                // Hide loader
                $rootScope.$broadcast("loader_hide");
            }

            return response || $q.when(response);
        },
        responseError: function (response) {
            if (!(--numLoadings)) {
                // Hide loader
                $rootScope.$broadcast("loader_hide");
            }
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    };
})
.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');
});
```

It's been slightly modified to fit my needs, but it essentially does the same thing.

I have a form that submits to an `iframe` to upload a file (due to browser support, I cannot use AJAX for this). I use the following code before starting the upload to turn on the loading spinner:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('loader_show');
```

and similarly use this code with `'loader_hide'` to hide the spinner.

The problem is that, during this upload of a large (~20MB) file, a keep-alive AJAX call turns off the spinner since the `numLoadings` part is not being incremented/decremented during the file upload process. Is there a way to access `httpInterceptor` in the controller that submits the form to deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being fairly inexperienced with AngularJS, I didn't realize that `httpInterceptor` in this case is just a service that's wired into `$httpProvider` as an interceptor. Once I grasped this concept, it was easy.

In the controller that is submitting the form, simply wire in the service like this and call `request`:

```
.controller('ConfigurationUploadFileCtrl', function($scope, httpInterceptor) {
  // this is called with ng-click on a button
  $scope.processForm = function(form) {
    httpInterceptor.request(); // turns on spinner
    // do stuff to submit the form...
  };
}
```

And in the callback (which is called from the iframe response):

```
function processFileUpload(data) {
  // do stuff to handle returned data, and then...
  angular.element('#configFileUploadForm')
         .injector().get('httpInterceptor').response(); // turns off spinner
}
```

Hope this helps somebody else!